# what is the different between class component and function component - React Native

Tags: function, react-native, class

I'm new to React Native and I'm planning to work with react hooks. But in order to use hooks I need to implement functional component instead of class component. So what are the major difference between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Class Components**

Class components are **JavaScript ES2015** classes that extend a base class from React called **Component**

```
class App extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <Text>Hello World!</Text>
        )
    }
}
```

This gives the class **App** access to the React lifecycle methods like render as well state/props functionality from the parent.

**Functional Components**

Functional components are simpler. They don’t manage their own state or have access to the lifecycle methods provided by React Native. They are literally plain old JavaScript functions. They are also known as stateless components.

```
const PageOne = () => {
    return (
       <Text>Hello World!</Text>
    );
}
```

**Conclusion**

Class components are used as container components to handle state management and wrap child components. Functional components generally are just used for display purposes - these components call functions from parent components to handle user interactions or state updates.

[Refer](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Answer (score 1):

Functional components were the one where you dont have access to any lifecycle methods of react and even local state. Its jjst a pure function.

In class based components you have access to lifecycle like , `componentDidMount` and can have a `local state` for that particular class.

Recently dan abramov introduced `react hooks`, which are functional components but have access to react lifecycle methods.

This link [react-hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) explains in details by comparing react class based components with react hooks.

Hopeit helps. feel free for doubts

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious one difference is the syntax. A functional component is just a plain JavaScript function which accepts props as an argument and returns a React element.

Class components are used as container components to handle state management and wrap child components. Functional components generally are just used for display purposes - these components call functions from parent components to handle user interactions or state updates.

1. Functional component are much easier to read and test because they
   are plain JavaScript functions without state or lifecycle-hooks You
   end up with less code They help you to use best practices.

   2. It will get easier to separate container and presentational components
      because you need to think more about your component’s state if you
      don’t have access to setState() in your component The React team
      mentioned that there may be a performance boost for functional
      component in future React versions

java Script fuction

```
function Test (props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
```

class function

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}
```