# problem with types of create react native apps

Tags: react-native

Hello I'm very beginner to react-native.
I have a problem
There are 2 ways to create react-native apps (Please check those examples from those image links)

first way is
[I got this method on documentation of react-native](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3XVf.png)

second way is
[this method is got from a you tube video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUFCv.png)

my problem is **Are those methods are same or what is the different between of those 2 ways.** Thank you very much your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first way is functional component and second one is class component. please check below links for explanations.

[what is the different between class component and function component - React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60487932/what-is-the-different-between-class-component-and-function-component-react-nat)

or google it like "**difference between functional component and class component**"

Comment: I understood. thank you for your help sir.